# Increase the size of cells in the list (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I've created a list but I don't know how to increase the size of cells. 
So I've got this problem : http://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/2-6166126-569357/450-446/test2.png

Do you how I can solved it ?

Here is my code :

```
package ca.xty.myUtils {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import fl.controls.List;
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
    import fl.data.DataProvider;

    public class AutoComplete extends Sprite {

        // These constant variables will be used in our event dispatches
        public static const SHOW_LIST:String = "SHOW_LIST";
        public static const MADE_CHOICE:String = "MADE_CHOICE";

        // These variables will be used to get information back to our Document Class which is why they have a public declaration
        public var aIndex:int;
        public var noResult:String;

        // These variables will hold the information contained in the parameters passed in the constructor
        private var _passedArray:Array;
        private var _txtWidth:int;
        private var _txtHeight:int;
        private var _whichProperty:String;
        private var _btnTxtColor:Number;

        // Display variables
        private var acList:List;
        private var acArray:Array;
        private var listHeight:int = 100;
        private var listHeightCalc:int;

        private var searchBtn:Button;
        private var sTerm:String;

        private var acTxt:TextField;

        // TextFormats
        private var titleFormat:TextFormat;
        private var topBtnFormat:TextFormat;

        // Convenience variables for loops 
        private var i:uint;
        private var len:uint;

        public function AutoComplete(PassedArray:Array, WhichProperty:String, TxtWidth:int, TxtHeight:int, BtnTxtColor:Number = 0x000000) {

            // Place the parameter values passed in the constructor into our private vars
            _passedArray = PassedArray;
            _txtWidth = TxtWidth;
            _txtHeight = TxtHeight;
            _whichProperty = WhichProperty;
            _btnTxtColor = BtnTxtColor;

            // Give our TextFormats some properties
            titleFormat = new TextFormat();
            titleFormat.size = 23;
            titleFormat.font = "ARIAL";
            titleFormat.leftMargin = 3;

            topBtnFormat = new TextFormat();
            topBtnFormat.color = 0x000000;
            topBtnFormat.size = 40;
            topBtnFormat.font = "ARIAL";

            // Call the function to build the display
            buildAC();

        }

        private function buildAC():void{
            // This is the TextField users will type in what they want to search for
            // It takes it's width and height from the variables passed in the constructor
            // The event listener responds to any change in the TextField
            var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    tf.size = 50;
             myFormat.size = 50;
    tf.font = "Time New Roman";



            acTxt = new TextField();
            acTxt.defaultTextFormat = tf;
            acTxt.x = -20;
            acTxt.y = 0;
            acTxt.width = 670;
            acTxt.height = 120;
            acTxt.type = "input";
            acTxt.border = true;
            acTxt.background = true;
            acTxt.textColor = 0x000000;
            acTxt.backgroundColor = 0xffffff;
            acTxt.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
            acTxt.sharpness = 100;
            acTxt.thickness = 100;
            acTxt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, updateDisplay);
            addChild(acTxt);

            // Our Search Button
            searchBtn = new Button();
            searchBtn.x = 140;
            searchBtn.y = 130;
            searchBtn.width = 300;
            searchBtn.height = 125;
            searchBtn.label = "RECHERCHER";
            searchBtn.setStyle("textFormat", topBtnFormat);
            searchBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, searchHandler);
            addChild(searchBtn);

            // The List component that will display the auto-complete results
            // Notice it has the visibale property set to false
            // It's event listener responds to a change, ie an item is clicked
            acList = new List();
            acList.setRendererStyle('textFormat',myFormat);
            acList.x = -20;
            acList.y = acTxt.y + acTxt.height;
            acList.setSize(645, 0); 

            acList.visible = false;
            acList.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, listHandler);
            addChild(acList);

        }

        // This is the function that fires when there is a change in the acTxt field
        private function updateDisplay(e:Event):void{
            // We set our variable sTerm to equal the value of the acTxt field
            sTerm = acTxt.text;
            // Set the sTerm to lower case
            sTerm = sTerm.toLowerCase();
            // Create an empty version of our acArray
            acArray = new Array();
            // Set the len variable to be that of the array we passed in through the constructor
            len = _passedArray.length;
            // Run a for loop to look through the array for items which match the sTerm
            for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
                // Create a variable to hold the first label item in our array and set it to be lower case
                var firstLabel:String = _passedArray[i][_whichProperty].toLowerCase();
                // Create a variable for the firstLetter using a sub string - the actual length of firstLetter will be determined by 
                // the length of sTerm so that firstLetter might really be first two letters...
                var firstLetter:String = firstLabel.substr(0, sTerm.length);
                // if the firstLetter var matches the STerm then we push corresponding item from the passed array into our acArray
                if(firstLetter == sTerm){
                    acArray.push({label:_passedArray[i][_whichProperty], data:i});
                }
            }
            // Once we've run through the whole array we calculate the List height
            listHeightCalc = acArray.length * 20;
            // if the calculated list height is greater than the variable listHeight then we set the height of the list to be listHeight ( our maximum height )
            // otherwise we set the height of the list to the calculated height
            if(listHeightCalc > listHeight){
                acList.height = listHeight;
            }else{
                acList.height = listHeightCalc;
            }
            // Clear our our List
            acList.removeAll();
            // Use the new acArray as the data provider
            acList.dataProvider = new DataProvider(acArray);
            // Make the list visble
            acList.visible = true;
            // Dispatch the event that will make sure the list is on top of all the othe diaply items
            dispatchEvent(new Event(AutoComplete.SHOW_LIST, true));
        }

        // This function handles the clicking of oneof the items in the List
        private function listHandler(e:Event):void{
            // Put the selected item's label in the acTxt field
            acTxt.text = e.target.selectedItem.label;
            // grab the data from the selected item and assign it to the aIndex variable
            aIndex = e.target.selectedItem.data;
            // Put the List's visibility back to false;
            acList.visible = false;
            // Dispatch the event to the Document class
            dispatchEvent(new Event(AutoComplete.MADE_CHOICE, true));
        }

        // This function handles a click of the Search Button
        private function searchHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
            // Reset the acArray to a nice new empty array
            acArray = new Array();
            // Reset the List's visible property to false;
            acList.visible = false;
            // Assign the contents of the acTxt field to our sTerm variable
            sTerm = acTxt.text;
            // Set the sTerm to lower case
            sTerm = sTerm.toLowerCase();
            // Loop throught the array and put matching items into our acArray
            for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
                var firstLabel:String = _passedArray[i][_whichProperty].toLowerCase();
                trace("firstLabel: " + firstLabel);
                trace("sTerm: " + sTerm);
                if(firstLabel.indexOf(sTerm) != -1){
                    acArray.push({label:_passedArray[i][_whichProperty], data:i});
                }
            }
            // Check to see if the calculated height for the List is bigger than the maximum height we set and build the List accordingly 
            listHeightCalc = acArray.length * 20;
            if(listHeightCalc > listHeight){
                acList.height = listHeight;
            }else{
                acList.height = listHeightCalc;
            }
            // If our acArray's length is greater than one we want to use the List to show you the result options
            // Once again we dispatch the event that will make sure the List is on the top of the diaply heap
            if(acArray.length > 1){
                acList.removeAll();
                acList.dataProvider = new DataProvider(acArray);
                acList.visible = true;
                dispatchEvent(new Event(AutoComplete.SHOW_LIST, true));
            // If our acArray's length is equal to 1, no need to set up the List, just stick it in our acTxt field
            // This time we dispatch the event that will display the results
            }else if(acArray.length == 1){
                acTxt.text = acArray[0].label;
                aIndex = acArray[0].data;
                dispatchEvent(new Event(AutoComplete.MADE_CHOICE, true));
            // If there are no results from our search, we set the aIndex variable to -1, create our noResults string and dispatch the event to display that result
            }else{
                aIndex = -1;
                noResult = "No Results for " + acTxt.text;
                dispatchEvent(new Event(AutoComplete.MADE_CHOICE, true));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You want to increase height or width or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase height of list's cell then use,

`acList.rowHeight = 50;`

Comment: And do you know how to increase the size of the scroll bar too....(sorry to ask you an other question...) ?

Comment: @user2421975 did you solve this? (Increasing the scroll bar) Can't find a solution, thanks!